# Whether to use chi square independence test?

Tags: independence, hypothesis-testing, chi-squared

If 140 girls (and let say out of them, 40 were blond) applied for 10 secretary jobs, and out of 10 admitted 7 were blond, can we claim that recruiter was biased towards blonds? Could we use chi square independence test to test it?

> tblBlond = data.frame(row.names=c('Blond','notBlond'), 
>   Job=c(7,3), noJob=c (33,97), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
>
> setDT(tblBlond)
>
> chisq.test(tblBlond)

and I got as output:

> Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
>
> data:  tblBlond
>   X-squared = 7.0027, df = 1, p-value = 0.008139
>
> Warning message:
>   In chisq.test(tblBlond) : Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect

What would be the most appropriate interpretation of test results?

Are the results of the test relevant since we do not have more than 5 obs in every cell? (since chi-sq <- normal <- binomial approximation).

Is this test in fact testing whether two variables (blonde and job) belong to binomial distributions with the same p (success probability)?

What else could be a problem while using chi square independence test?

Comment: If 137 applicants were blond, the recruiter was obviously biased  *against* blonds.

Comment: ok, but could we use (and how) contingency table to test whether getting a secretary job is independent of hair color? I am trying to understand  how chi square independence test work and what are underlying assumptions that have to be met in order for test to produce relevant results.

Comment: You need to know the fraction of blonds in the applicant group. That was the whole point of my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am generally against saying that we could "prove" that the recruiter was biased, as "prove" seems to strong of a word. However, a $\chi^2$ test of independence would indeed provide significant **evidence** of it.

Your null hypothesis would be the following: Hair color and job acceptance are independent. As for how to perform the $\chi^2$ test, here's a very good [resource](http://stattrek.com/chi-square-test/independence.aspx?Tutorial=AP).

Once you perform the test, you can receive a $p$-value, which tells you the chance that, given your null hypothesis, this outcome would occur. If the $p$-value is sufficiently low, you conclude it is likely that the two are not independent, and hence the recruiter was biased.